# Callback once chat is ready

Tags: javascript, botframework

I am building a ChatBot service using the Microsoft Bot Framework, over Azure as the service, and QnA Maker for the key-value-pairs.

In our implementation, we are having everything completely hosted in the cloud using Azure, and therefore, we do NOT have access to any code-behind for the framework. It is all done in JS via the webpage. No "cards" or special "interfaces" that we can push through from the back-end. As such, I have had to implement a bit of a "hack" in that, I have implemented my own JS functionality, which, when the page loads, sends out a message on behalf of the user in order to trigger a QnA Maker response.

The issue I am having is that even though the DOM may be ready, the ChatBot implementation and back-end service, may not! It may still be in a "connecting..." or loading state and therefore, when my JS tries to send out the message, it simply does not fire, <strike>because the button to send the message is disabled until the service is ready</strike>. This part is all controlled by the bot framework. Therefore, on some instantiations (usually on the first ones for the day or the first one after a while without it being used), the message "Hi! I have a question..." remains in the "User chat bar" and never fires.

Here is my question: Is there a way for me to have the bot framework perform a Callback once it is ready to receive input? If so, where would I place that callback in the JS implementation? <strike>Or alternatively, how could I "wait until the button is enabled" before firing off the send event?</strike>

Let me know if this is not clear or if you need more information.

**UPDATE**

Upon verification, the button is NOT even disabled while the chatbot is connecting to the service, so even that option is not available. A callback seems the only possible way of achieving this?

**UPDATE --> SOLUTION!**
In case anyone is wondering how to do this, here is a working example that shows you exactly how. This was amalgamated from different GitHub instructions pages for the BotFramework, which Steven Kanberg provided in the comments below. Thanks!

```js
//This is how you build your store, and load the web chat... StyleOptions is a constant that is up to you to create.

const token = 'ENTER YOUR SECRET HERE';

const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
     if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
          const event = new Event('webchatreadyactivity');
          event.data = action.payload.activity;
          window.dispatchEvent(event);

          // When we receive DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED action, we will send an event activity using WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT
          dispatch({
               type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
               payload: {
                    name: 'webchat/join',
                    value: { language: window.navigator.language }
               }
          });
     }
     return next(action);
});

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
     directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
     store,
     styleOptions
}, document.getElementById("ENTER CHAT ELEMENT ID HERE"));

//THEN, simply hook onto the event like this, to send your initial message...
//This event will fire only ONCE, and only once the chat is READY.
window.addEventListener('webchatreadyactivity', ({ data }) => {
//this is yours to build as well...
sendWelcomeMessage(); 
});
```

Comment: Are you using BotFramework-WebChat for the client/channel, or some other channel?

Comment: BotFramework for the client... on a plain old HTML page...azure is hosting the BotMaker service which connects to QnA Maker...

Comment: Do you not have access to the code in Azure because of permissions / rights? If that is not the case, then the code **is** accessible either in the cloud. From the bot's settings, select Bot Management => Build. From here you can download the code or access the online editor.

Comment: That being said, the [BotFramework-WebChat](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/551524-language-understanding-luis) repo has a variety of samples showing different functionalities. For instance, [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event) sample shows how to trigger events only after the bot has connected. In this way, via `styleOptions`, you may be able to initially turn off the `sendBox` until the bot has connected.

Comment: Also, the app service configuration for the bot may have the "Always on" feature set to off. The result is after periods of inactivity the app will need to "wake up" which will take time when loading on a page.

Comment: Hi, please post the comment that you posted which I have upvoted, and I will accept it as the answer. I used a combination of both this: [Send Welcome Event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event) ... and this [Forward All Incoming Activity to JavaScript Event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.b.incoming-activity-event) .. and now the welcome message gets displayed only when the chat is ready :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) repo has a variety of samples showing different functionalities. For instance, [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event) shows how to trigger events only after the bot has connected. In this way, via `styleOptions`, you may be able to initially turn off the `sendBox` until the bot has connected.

Hope of help!